# How to reload Apache Kafka certificates without restart/downtime?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, openssl

I'm using [Kafka in bitnami Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/) and Let's Encrypt certificate for it. How can I reload Kafka to take new certificate without downtime (full restart and disconnecting clients)? Thanks.

Comment: A rolling restart will be required and be transparent to clients as they attempt retries